# I need a function that returns only the titles of my structures in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, function, struct, swiftui

So this might be simple fix, but I am pretty new to Xcode and SwiftUI. I have a structure that includes a title as a property, and I am trying to list only the titles in a search bar inside a tab view, here is what I got so far, the only function that is working for me is randomElement()!, which only shows one random title in my list obviously

here is where I want to place the function

```
TabView {
        Searchbar(duaa: .constant(Duaa.demoDuaa.randomElement()!))
        .tabItem {
        VStack {
               Image(systemName: "book.circle")
                 .renderingMode(.original)
                 Text(verbatim: "PRAYERS")
                }
           }.tag(2)
}
```

and this is the code of my structure

```
import SwiftUI

struct Duaa: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var imageName: String
  var duaaContext: String
  var duaabenefit: String
  var isLiked = false
}

extension Duaa: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: Duaa, rhs: Duaa) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

    }
extension Duaa {
  static let demoDuaa = [
    Duaa(title: "blue", imageName: "blueimage"),
    Duaa(title: "yellow", imageName: "yellowimage"),
    Duaa(title: "Orange", imageName: "orangeimage"),
    Duaa(title: "Green", imageName: "greenimage"),
    Duaa(title: "Purple", imageName: "purpleimage")
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of `Duaa` objects, you can map over it and pull out the titles easily.

`var duaaTitles = arrayOfDuaas.map{ $0.title }`

That will create an array of titles.

Even better would be a `.compactMap{}` because that will eliminate any possible nils.

You’ll need to show more of your code (like your `Searchbar` implementation) if you want specific help.

Also, you’re doing a lot of work with the static struct definition `Duaa` (like a blueprint of a Duaa rather than an actual Duaa), rather than an instance of it. Is that on purpose?